# What is the name of the black&white movie about a mirror Earth (universe)?

Tags: story-identification, movie

Astronauts in a spaceship have an accident and fall back to the Earth. They are tried in court. It turns out to be a mirror Earth. As I remember (though maybe I'm not totally right) only one professor knows something about that and in the final scene he crashes into a mirror with his wheelchair. In another scene an astronaut realizes that his name can be read from the mirror directly.

Does anybody remember the movie?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> [Doppelgänger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelg%C3%A4nger_%281969_film%29) is a 1969 British science-fiction film directed by Robert Parrish ...Outside Europe, it is known as Journey to the Far Side of the Sun, which is now the more popular title. In the film, a joint European-NASA mission to investigate a planet in a position parallel to Earth behind the Sun ends in disaster with the death of one of the astronauts (Hendry). His colleague (Thinnes) discovers that the planet is a mirror image of Earth.

Does that sound right?

Comment: exactly... thanks...